# Calculating average of a range in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have cells with a range in mysql

```
example 
20 - 24
25 - 29
30 - 34
```

I would like to calculate the midpoint of each one
The column data type is text

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH datatable (example) AS (
  SELECT '20 - 24' UNION ALL
  SELECT '25 - 29' UNION ALL
  SELECT '30 - 34'
  )
SELECT example,
       (SUBSTRING_INDEX(example, '-', 1) + SUBSTRING_INDEX(example, '-', -1)) / 2 average
FROM datatable;
```

| example | average |
| --- | --- |
| 20 - 24 | 22 |
| 25 - 29 | 27 |
| 30 - 34 | 32 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EW_M6AsQ)